# Backing up directory using CodeIgniter Zip library not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my function:

```
function backup() 
{ 
    $this->load->library('zip'); 
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); 
    $this->zip->read_dir($path.'/assets/');
    $this->zip->archive('backup.zip'); 
    $this->zip->download('backup.zip');
}
```

When I access the function, my browser pauses for a good 10-15 seconds, which, I assume, means an archive is being made. However, nothing happens except for a 500 error when the loading is completed.

Unfortunately, I don't have direct access to this server via FTP, otherwise I'd check my logs. Any idea if perhaps my code is wrong? My app is on a IIS7 installation.

Comment: Have you tried to make errors just show up on the output with `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`? I assume that the scripts just runs out of memory at the end. Also, is there anything in CI's application/logs/ directory?

Comment: Does this library raise exceptions? If so, use `try/catch`.

Comment: Also, what is your `max_execution_time` set to? See http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

Comment: As you're on IIS, is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` set?

Answer (score 1):

> By default the Zip archive will place all directories listed in the
>   first parameter inside the zip. If you want the tree preceding the
>   target folder to be ignored you can pass **`FALSE`**

so the 500 internal server error is coming from the `max_execution_time` most likely because you are compressing every directory in your path. or you are having a `permission error`.
in both ways what you have to do is either use:

```
 $this->zip->read_dir($path.'/assets/', FALSE);
```

**or:**

```
$this->zip->read_dir('assets/');
```

will work too.

I just tried it and it's working!

Answer (score 1):

```
function back_up(){ 
    $this->load->library('zip'); 
    $path = 'application/'; 
    $time = time();
    $this->zip->read_dir($path);  
    $result = $this->zip->download('backup.'.$time.'.zip'); 
    return $result;  
}
```

This function above will backup your **application** folder.
Just example, try with your own folder.

*I speak English not well, so sorry.*